# VDR ist not starting at boottime

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, boot

I have an Ubuntu 12.04 system with vdr installed. But when I boot the system vdr does not start due to errors I don't understand.
Here is the syslog:

```
Feb 18 00:53:57 glubschi vdr: [2302] VDR version 1.7.22 started
Feb 18 00:53:57 glubschi vdr: [2302] switched to user 'root'
Feb 18 00:53:57 glubschi vdr: [2302] codeset is 'UTF-8' - known
Feb 18 00:53:57 glubschi vdr: [2302] found 28 locales in /usr/share/locale
Feb 18 00:53:57 glubschi vdr: [2302] loading plugin: /usr/lib/vdr/plugins/libvdr-quickepgsearch.so.1.7.22
Feb 18 00:53:57 glubschi vdr: [2302] loading plugin: /usr/lib/vdr/plugins/libvdr-osdteletext.so.1.7.22
Feb 18 00:53:57 glubschi vdr: [2302] loading plugin: /usr/lib/vdr/plugins/libvdr-epgsearch.so.1.7.22
Feb 18 00:53:57 glubschi vdr: [2302] loading plugin: /usr/lib/vdr/plugins/libvdr-svdrposd.so.1.7.22
Feb 18 00:53:57 glubschi vdr: [2302] loading plugin: /usr/lib/vdr/plugins/libvdr-prefermenu.so.1.7.22
Feb 18 00:53:57 glubschi vdr: [2302] loading plugin: /usr/lib/vdr/plugins/libvdr-femon.so.1.7.22
Feb 18 00:53:57 glubschi vdr: [2302] loading plugin: /usr/lib/vdr/plugins/libvdr-dvbsddevice.so.1.7.22
Feb 18 00:53:57 glubschi vdr: [2302] loading plugin: /usr/lib/vdr/plugins/libvdr-xineliboutput.so.1.7.22
Feb 18 00:53:57 glubschi vdr: [2302] [xine..put] Listening on address '192.168.2.51' port 37890
Feb 18 00:53:57 glubschi vdr: [2302] loading plugin: /usr/lib/vdr/plugins/libvdr-live.so.1.7.22
Feb 18 00:53:57 glubschi vdr: [2302] loading plugin: /usr/lib/vdr/plugins/libvdr-epgsearchonly.so.1.7.22
Feb 18 00:53:57 glubschi vdr: [2302] loading plugin: /usr/lib/vdr/plugins/libvdr-conflictcheckonly.so.1.7.22
Feb 18 00:53:57 glubschi vdr: [2302] loading plugin: /usr/lib/vdr/plugins/libvdr-dvbhddevice.so.1.7.22
Feb 18 00:53:57 glubschi vdr: [2302] loading /var/lib/vdr/setup.conf
Feb 18 00:53:57 glubschi vdr: [2302] loading /var/lib/vdr/sources.conf
Feb 18 00:53:57 glubschi vdr: [2302] loading /var/lib/vdr/diseqc.conf
Feb 18 00:53:57 glubschi vdr: [2302] loading /var/lib/vdr/channels.conf
Feb 18 00:53:57 glubschi vdr: [2302] loading /var/lib/vdr/timers.conf
Feb 18 00:53:57 glubschi vdr: [2302] loading /var/lib/vdr/commands.conf
Feb 18 00:53:57 glubschi vdr: [2302] loading /var/lib/vdr/reccmds.conf
Feb 18 00:53:57 glubschi vdr: [2302] loading /var/lib/vdr/svdrphosts.conf
Feb 18 00:53:57 glubschi vdr: [2302] loading /var/lib/vdr/remote.conf
Feb 18 00:53:57 glubschi vdr: [2302] loading /var/lib/vdr/keymacros.conf
Feb 18 00:53:57 glubschi vdr: [2302] reading EPG data from /var/cache/vdr/epg.data
Feb 18 00:53:57 glubschi vdr: [2304] video directory scanner thread started (pid=2302, tid=2304)
Feb 18 00:53:57 glubschi vdr: [2303] video directory scanner thread started (pid=2302, tid=2303)
Feb 18 00:53:57 glubschi vdr: [2302] registered source parameters for 'A - ATSC'
Feb 18 00:53:57 glubschi vdr: [2302] registered source parameters for 'C - DVB-C'
Feb 18 00:53:57 glubschi vdr: [2302] registered source parameters for 'S - DVB-S'
Feb 18 00:53:57 glubschi vdr: [2302] registered source parameters for 'T - DVB-T'
Feb 18 00:53:57 glubschi vdr: [2302] probing /dev/dvb/adapter0/frontend0
Feb 18 00:53:57 glubschi vdr: [2302] creating cDvbDevice
Feb 18 00:53:57 glubschi vdr: [2302] new device number 1
Feb 18 00:53:58 glubschi vdr: [2304] video directory scanner thread ended (pid=2302, tid=2304)
Feb 18 00:53:58 glubschi vdr: [2303] video directory scanner thread ended (pid=2302, tid=2303)
Feb 18 00:54:00 glubschi vdr: [2302] frontend 0/0 provides DVB-T with QPSK,QAM16,QAM64 ("Philips TDA10046H DVB-T")
Feb 18 00:54:00 glubschi vdr: [2413] tuner on frontend 0/0 thread started (pid=2302, tid=2413)
Feb 18 00:54:00 glubschi vdr: [2302] probing /dev/dvb/adapter1/frontend0
Feb 18 00:54:00 glubschi vdr: [2413] cTimeMs: using monotonic clock (resolution is 1 ns)
Feb 18 00:54:00 glubschi vdr: [2302] creating cDvbDevice
Feb 18 00:54:00 glubschi vdr: [2302] new device number 2
Feb 18 00:54:00 glubschi vdr: [2414] section handler thread started (pid=2302, tid=2414)
Feb 18 00:54:02 glubschi vdr: [2302] frontend 1/0 provides DVB-T with QPSK,QAM16,QAM64 ("Philips TDA10046H DVB-T")
Feb 18 00:54:02 glubschi vdr: [2302] found 2 DVB devices
Feb 18 00:54:02 glubschi vdr: [2302] initializing plugin: quickepgsearch (0.0.1): Schnelle Suche nach Sendungen
Feb 18 00:54:02 glubschi vdr: [2302] initializing plugin: osdteletext (0.9.1): Zeigt den Videotext auf dem OSD an
Feb 18 00:54:02 glubschi vdr: [2302] initializing plugin: epgsearch (1.0.0): Suche im EPG nach Wiederholungen und anderem
Feb 18 00:54:02 glubschi vdr: [2302] initializing plugin: svdrposd (0.1.1): Publish OSD menu via SVDRP
Feb 18 00:54:02 glubschi vdr: [2302] initializing plugin: prefermenu (0.6.6): Prefer Channel Menu
Feb 18 00:54:02 glubschi vdr: [2302] initializing plugin: femon (1.7.11): DVB Signal Informationsanzeige (OSD)
Feb 18 00:54:02 glubschi vdr: [2302] initializing plugin: dvbsddevice (0.0.5): SD Full Featured DVB device
Feb 18 00:54:02 glubschi vdr: [2302] initializing plugin: xineliboutput (1.0.90-cvs): X11/xine-lib Ausgabe-Plugin
Feb 18 00:54:02 glubschi vdr: [2302] new device number 9
Feb 18 00:54:02 glubschi vdr: [2457] section handler thread started (pid=2302, tid=2457)
Feb 18 00:54:02 glubschi vdr: [2302] [xine..put] cTimePts: clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC): clock resolution 0 us
Feb 18 00:54:02 glubschi vdr: [2302] [xine..put] cTimePts: using monotonic clock
Feb 18 00:54:02 glubschi vdr: [2302] [xine..put] RTP SSRC: 0x71386ca7
Feb 18 00:54:02 glubschi vdr: [2302] initializing plugin: live (0.2.0): Live Interactive VDR Environment
Feb 18 00:54:02 glubschi vdr: [2302] initializing plugin: epgsearchonly (0.0.1): Direkter Zugriff auf epgsearch's Suchenmenu
Feb 18 00:54:02 glubschi vdr: [2302] initializing plugin: conflictcheckonly (0.0.1): Direkter Zugriff auf epgsearch's Konflikt-Prüfungs-Menü
Feb 18 00:54:02 glubschi vdr: [2302] initializing plugin: dvbhddevice (0.0.4): HD Full Featured DVB device
Feb 18 00:54:02 glubschi vdr: [2302] setting primary device to 3
Feb 18 00:54:02 glubschi vdr: [2302] assuming manual start of VDR
Feb 18 00:54:02 glubschi vdr: [2302] SVDRP listening on port 6419
Feb 18 00:54:02 glubschi vdr: [2302] setting current skin to "sttng"
Feb 18 00:54:02 glubschi vdr: [2302] loading /var/lib/vdr/themes/sttng-default.theme
Feb 18 00:54:02 glubschi vdr: [2302] starting plugin: quickepgsearch
Feb 18 00:54:02 glubschi vdr: [2302] starting plugin: osdteletext
Feb 18 00:54:02 glubschi vdr: [2302] starting plugin: epgsearch
Feb 18 00:54:02 glubschi vdr: [2302] loading /var/lib/vdr/plugins/epgsearch/epgsearchcats.conf
Feb 18 00:54:02 glubschi vdr: [2302] loading /var/lib/vdr/plugins/epgsearch/epgsearchmenu.conf
Feb 18 00:54:02 glubschi vdr: [2302] EPGSearch: loading /var/lib/vdr/plugins/epgsearch/epgsearch.conf
Feb 18 00:54:02 glubschi vdr: [2302] EPGSearch: loading /var/lib/vdr/plugins/epgsearch/epgsearchdone.data
Feb 18 00:54:02 glubschi vdr: [2302] loading /var/lib/vdr/plugins/epgsearch/timersdone.conf
Feb 18 00:54:02 glubschi vdr: [2302] EPGSearch: loading /var/lib/vdr/plugins/epgsearch/epgsearchupdmail.templ
Feb 18 00:54:02 glubschi vdr: [2302] starting plugin: svdrposd
Feb 18 00:54:02 glubschi vdr: [2302] starting plugin: prefermenu
Feb 18 00:54:02 glubschi vdr: [2302] plugin 'prefermenu' called obsolete function RegisterI18n()
Feb 18 00:54:02 glubschi vdr: [2302] starting plugin: femon
Feb 18 00:54:02 glubschi vdr: [2302] starting plugin: dvbsddevice
Feb 18 00:54:02 glubschi vdr: [2302] starting plugin: xineliboutput
Feb 18 00:54:02 glubschi vdr: [2456] tuner on frontend 1/0 thread started (pid=2302, tid=2456)
Feb 18 00:54:02 glubschi vdr: [2459] EPGSearch: searchtimer thread started (pid=2302, tid=2459)
Feb 18 00:54:02 glubschi vdr: [2461] Remote decoder/display server (cXinelibServer) thread started (pid=2302, tid=2461)
Feb 18 00:54:02 glubschi vdr: [2461] [xine..put] cXinelibServer priority set successful SCHED_RR 2 [1,99]
Feb 18 00:54:02 glubschi vdr: [2461] [xine..put] Binding server to 192.168.2.51:37890
Feb 18 00:54:02 glubschi vdr: [2460] EPGSearch: conflictcheck thread started (pid=2302, tid=2460)
Feb 18 00:54:02 glubschi vdr: [2461] [xine..put] cXinelibServer: bind error 192.168.2.51 port 37890: Die angeforderte Adresse kann nicht zugewiesen werden
Feb 18 00:54:02 glubschi vdr: [2461] [xine..put]    (ERROR (frontend_svr.c,860): Die angeforderte Adresse kann nicht zugewiesen werden)
Feb 18 00:54:02 glubschi vdr: [2461] [discovery] UDP broadcast send failed (discovery)
Feb 18 00:54:02 glubschi vdr: [2461] [discovery]    (ERROR (tools/vdrdiscovery.c,97): Das Netzwerk ist nicht erreichbar)
Feb 18 00:54:02 glubschi vdr: [2461] Remote decoder/display server (cXinelibServer) thread ended (pid=2302, tid=2461)
Feb 18 00:54:02 glubschi vdr: [2302] [xine..put] cXinelibDevice::Start(): Server init failed
Feb 18 00:54:02 glubschi vdr: [2302] stopping plugin: dvbsddevice
Feb 18 00:54:02 glubschi vdr: [2302] stopping plugin: femon
Feb 18 00:54:02 glubschi vdr: [2302] stopping plugin: prefermenu
Feb 18 00:54:02 glubschi vdr: [2302] stopping plugin: svdrposd
Feb 18 00:54:02 glubschi vdr: [2302] stopping plugin: epgsearch
Feb 18 00:54:02 glubschi vdr: [2459] EPGSearch: Leaving search timer thread
Feb 18 00:54:02 glubschi vdr: [2459] EPGSearch: searchtimer thread ended (pid=2302, tid=2459)
Feb 18 00:54:02 glubschi vdr: [2302] stopping plugin: osdteletext
Feb 18 00:54:02 glubschi vdr: [2302] stopping plugin: quickepgsearch
Feb 18 00:54:02 glubschi vdr: [2302] [xine..put] cXinelibOsdProvider: shutting down !
Feb 18 00:54:03 glubschi vdr: [2414] section handler thread ended (pid=2302, tid=2414)
Feb 18 00:54:03 glubschi vdr: [2413] tuner on frontend 0/0 thread ended (pid=2302, tid=2413)
Feb 18 00:54:03 glubschi vdr: [2457] section handler thread ended (pid=2302, tid=2457)
Feb 18 00:54:03 glubschi vdr: [2456] tuner on frontend 1/0 thread ended (pid=2302, tid=2456)
Feb 18 00:54:03 glubschi vdr: [2302] [xine..put] cXinelibDevice::StopDevice(): Stopping device ...
Feb 18 00:54:03 glubschi vdr: [2302] deleting plugin: dvbhddevice
Feb 18 00:54:03 glubschi vdr: [2302] deleting plugin: conflictcheckonly
Feb 18 00:54:03 glubschi vdr: [2302] deleting plugin: epgsearchonly
Feb 18 00:54:03 glubschi vdr: [2302] deleting plugin: live
Feb 18 00:54:03 glubschi vdr: [2302] deleting plugin: xineliboutput
Feb 18 00:54:03 glubschi vdr: [2302] deleting plugin: dvbsddevice
Feb 18 00:54:03 glubschi vdr: [2302] deleting plugin: femon
Feb 18 00:54:03 glubschi vdr: [2302] deleting plugin: prefermenu
Feb 18 00:54:03 glubschi vdr: [2302] deleting plugin: svdrposd
Feb 18 00:54:03 glubschi vdr: [2302] deleting plugin: epgsearch
Feb 18 00:54:03 glubschi vdr: [2460] EPGSearch: Leaving conflict check thread
Feb 18 00:54:03 glubschi vdr: [2460] EPGSearch: conflictcheck thread ended (pid=2302, tid=2460)
Feb 18 00:54:03 glubschi vdr: [2302] deleting plugin: osdteletext
Feb 18 00:54:03 glubschi vdr: [2302] deleting plugin: quickepgsearch
Feb 18 00:54:04 glubschi vdr: [2302] exiting, exit code 2
```

It seems to me that a second instance of vdr[2460] tries to bind the adress 192.68.2.51:37890. That fails and kills both instances. 
I have no idea where the second instance comes from.

Does anybody have an idea how to solve this ?

Comment: The reason was no network configuration was setup at boot time.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that xine is not working correctly because `Das Netzwerk ist nicht erreichbar`. This stops vdr:

```
[2461] [xine..put] cXinelibServer: bind error 192.168.2.51 port 37890: Die angeforderte Adresse kann nicht zugewiesen werden
[2461] [xine..put]    (ERROR (frontend_svr.c,860): Die angeforderte Adresse kann nicht zugewiesen werden)
[2461] [discovery] UDP broadcast send failed (discovery)
[2461] [discovery]    (ERROR (tools/vdrdiscovery.c,97): Das Netzwerk ist nicht erreichbar)
```

The network seems to be ok:

```
Feb 18 00:53:57 glubschi vdr: [2302] [xine..put] Listening on address '192.168.2.51' port 37890
```